# string formatting in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, printf

I am writing simple debugging/logging functions using ring-buffer in a chunk of the global memory. The problem is lack of any `snprintf`-like function in OpenCL. What would be the suggestion? To use some embedded implementation, and extend the format specification for vector types?

(Please do not reply that string ops are inefficient and that OpenCL is designed for computations; I know that.)

Answer (score 1):

Some CPU implementations support printf etc, so that might help if your implementation does not rely on unsported work-group dimensions. When I worked with OpenCL I usually would do the verification on the host side, i.e. implement the buffer-reading algorithm and then write the data back using a 1:1 map of the work items to the result buffer. This makes it quite easy to verfiy as you know which thread wrote what given the index in the result buffer. It might be a good idea to initalize the client buffer with known data (i.e copy a host buffer into the reuslt buffer before executing the kernel) to avoid confusion.

I realize this isn't a very technical answer, but I hope it helps somewhat.